# Inject custom AmazonS3 client object into Spring Cloud Config server instead of using the one provided by S3 backend

Tags: spring-cloud-config-server

With the below Spring Cloud Config configuration (S3 backend), I am able fetch the config from S3 with my personal AWS account from personal laptop. However, within our client environment I am unable to use this configuration because my client has custom logic in creating the AmazonS3 object with corporate proxy and other security configurations.

Question:

1. Is there a way we can inject custom AmazonS3 object into Spring Cloud Config server? If yes, please let me know how I could inject it.
2. If #1 is not possible, is there a way I can pass custom AWSCredentialsProvider with Http proxy?

```
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    stack:
      auto: false
    credentials:
      accessKey: XXXX
      secretKey: YYYY
      instance-profile: false
      useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: true
spring:
  profiles:
    active: awss3
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        awss3:
          region: us-east-1
          bucket: test-bucket-name/bucket-folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using a configuration bean as shown below. Please check that I am creating an AmazonS3 object programmatically. There you have full control on how to create this object (with proxy parameters if needed)

```
package com.mypackage.product.config.server.config;

import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsS3EnvironmentProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsS3EnvironmentRepository;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsS3EnvironmentRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.AwsCodeCommitCredentialProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ScalityEnvironmentRepository {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigServerProperties server;

    @Autowired
    AwsS3EnvironmentRepositoryFactory awsS3EnvironmentRepositoryFactory;

    @Autowired
    AwsS3EnvironmentProperties awsS3EnvironmentProperties;

    // read aws/scality creds from vault
    @Value("${data.AccessKeyId}")
    String accessKeyId;

    @Value("${data.SecretAccessKey}")
    String secretAccessKey;

    @Bean
    AwsS3EnvironmentRepository getAwsS3EnvironmentRepository() {

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);

        AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration epc = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                "https://corporate.scality.url.com",
                awsS3EnvironmentProperties.getRegion());

        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider =
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds);

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration()
                .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
                .withMaxErrorRetry(3)
                .withSocketTimeout(50000)
                .withClientExecutionTimeout(50000);

        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(epc)
                .build(); 

        AwsS3EnvironmentRepository repository = new AwsS3EnvironmentRepository(client,
                awsS3EnvironmentProperties.getBucket(), server);    

        return  repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you want to add comments about what your method did that is different than what the question code provided?

Comment: @benhorgen, I have added a comment on how I am creating an AmazonS3 object and there the OP can modify it as he likes.

Comment: I think that helps. Thank you.